# IOS Fingerprint implementation

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, fingerprint

Since Apple has release Xcode 5 which features FingerPrint scanning in iOS 7, Can we implement this in our app? if yes which SDK do we use for implementation.

Please provide a sample code or else specify which SDK do we use.

Comment: @rckoenes is right the `apple dev center forum discussion` about read this [Is the fingerprint sensor available for other apps?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/884859#884859)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by using **LAContext**(*Local Authentication framework*) which can be use to evaluate a security policy.It checks, using the Touch ID sensor, that the person authenticating is the device owner. In the future there may be other security policies.

Here is the code snippet for the same:

```
-(void)handlerForFingerTouch{
   LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

   NSError *error = nil;
   if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
       [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
               localizedReason:@"Are you the device owner?"
                         reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

           if (error) {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                               message:@"There was a problem verifying your identity."
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];
               return;
           }

           if (success) {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                               message:@"You are the device owner!"
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];

           } else {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                               message:@"You are not the device owner."
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];
           }

       }];

   } else {

       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                       message:@"Your device cannot authenticate using TouchID."
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No the fingerprint scanner is not available to developers, it is available in the current SDK.

With the upcoming iOS 8 SDK you will be able to use the fingerprintscanner via the official SDK.

You can read more about TouchID in the [What's New in iOS: iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW2) document.

Comment: This is changing in iOS 8.

Comment: @Zaph You are right, But since I don't go thru all my posted and change them every time a new SDK comes out this answer is not updated.